# How to properly destroy a Toplevel widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy, toplevel

I'm somewhat new to python and I'm trying to write my first GUI. I'm having problems when destroying a `Toplevel` widget. somehow my script gets stuck in a loop.

Basically, I have a button (in this case <kbd>Hours left</kbd>) when I press it, it should take me to a function that executes some code. If one condition is met (no credentials found) then it needs to open a `Toplevel` window where the user enters their credentials. Once they click on <kbd>Log in</kbd> the `Toplevel` window must be destroyed and the code should carry on with the rest of the commands in my function.

The problem is that when I destroy the `Toplevel` window my script enters a loop and it doesn't execute anything else. Here is a simplified version of my code

```
from tkinter import *

def loginSequence():
    print("loginSequence")

def logoutSequence():
    print("logoutSequence")

def hoursLeft():
    print("hoursLeft")
    input("Do something and press enter")
    credentialsWindow()
    print("Why is this message not printing?")
    """Rest of the code goes here"""

def credentialsWindow():
    global credentials
    credentials = Toplevel()

    Label(credentials, text='Opss... I Could not find your credentials.\nPlease, log back in', font=40).pack()

    Button(credentials, text='Log in', command=doSomethingandClose).pack()

    Button(credentials, text='Cancel', command=destroyNewWindow).pack()

    credentials.mainloop()

def doSomethingandClose():
    input("Do something and press enter 2 destroy")
    destroyNewWindow()

def destroyNewWindow():
    credentials.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Define the main screen for Ultipro Logger
    logger_Root = Tk()

    header = Label(logger_Root, text="Welcome to UltiPro Logger", font=40).pack()

    # Login button
    login_PB = Button(logger_Root, text="   Clock in    ", font=40, bg="gray", command=loginSequence).pack()

    # Logout button
    logout_PB = Button(logger_Root, text="   Clock out  ", font=40, bg="gray", command=logoutSequence).pack()

    # Hours left alarm button
    ResetAlarm_PB = Button(logger_Root, text="   Hours left  ", font=40, bg="gray", command=hoursLeft).pack()

    # Exit button
    exit_PB = Button(logger_Root, text="  Exit  ", anchor='se', justify='right', bg="gray", command=logger_Root.quit).pack()

    logger_Root.mainloop()
```

If you run it and click "hours left" and then either cancel or log in it doesn't execute

```
print("Why is this message not printing?")
    """Rest of the code goes here"""
```

What's even weirder is that if you go back to the main menu and click exit, that piece of code will get executed. if you click exit again then the main window will close.

I have no clue why this is happening. I've been stuck for 3 days trying to figure it out but all the tkinter tutorials I've seen are pretty simple.

Comment: You should not be calling `mainloop` in `credentialsWindow`. You only need to call `mainloop` once.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I had the `mainloop` there because my code is divided in 3 different scpits, so the second window would not show unless I put a `mainloop` there. However removing the `mainloop` in this example doesn't change the outcome, the rest of my code still doesn't excecute

Comment: Change `credentials.mainloop()` to `credentials.wait_window(credentials)`.

Comment: It looks like that fixed the problem!!! thank you so much

Comment: We have no way of knowing you have multiple scripts. All we have to go on is what is in the question. When I remove the call to `credentials.mainloop()`, the message ""Why is this message not printing?"" is printed.

Comment: My bad Bryan. I am also using this script for debugging, when I get rid of `credentials.mainllop` it prints the message, but it shouldn't do that until the window is destroyed. acw1668's method works like a charm